# Ignoring blank dropdown values in an AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a tabular list of user data which I'm adding 'advanced search' functionality to. The advanced search consists of a number of dropdowns allowing users to filter their results, for example, limiting the results to users from a particular department:

```
<select ng-model="search.department_id" ng-options="department.id as department.name for department in departments">
    <option value="">(Select from list)</option>
</select>
```

The results are then displayed using:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search | orderBy:'name')">
        <td> [code to show user data here.] </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you select a department from the dropdown, this works correctly. But if you change your mind and pick the default '(Select from list)' option again, only users with a *blank* department_id value are shown. What I want to happen is for the department dropdown to be ignored if no department is selected.

After some searching around, it looked like I could solve this using a custom comparator, so I wrote this:

```
$scope.ignoreNullComparator = function(expected, actual){
    if (expected === null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return angular.equals(expected, actual);
    }
};
```

and changed the `ng-repeat` to:

```
ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:ignoreNullComparator | orderBy:'name'
```

but although with some debugging could see the custom comparator being used, it didn't make any difference to the results.

So, how can I get the filter to ignore the dropdowns if the blank option is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of parameters in your comparator is wrong, comparator should be defined as `function(actual, expected)`:

```
$scope.ignoreNullComparator = function(actual, expected){
    if (expected === null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return angular.equals(expected, actual);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had a feeling it'd be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

**i update the function to work with string and number search fields**

```js
$scope.ignoreNullComparator = function(actual, expected){            
            if (expected === null || expected === '' || typeof expected === "undefined") {
                return true;
            } else   if(!isNaN(expected)) {
                expected2 = parseInt(expected);
                return angular.equals(expected2, actual);
            } else  if( actual.indexOf(expected) === -1 ){
                return false;
            }
            return true;        
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```